# Using Division with Remainder Theorem to Prove Finiteness of a Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Division with Remainder Theorem:

Let $m \le n$ be natural numbers. Then, there are unique natural numbers $k$ and $r$ so that $r < m$ and $n = km + r$.

My goal is to use the Division with Remainder Theorem to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are finite then $A \times B$ is also finite. However, I am really not seeing how this theorem will be at all useful in a proof of this kind. The claim seems so obvious that I feel as if the question is more complicated than it needs to be

Could someone show how the theorem could be applied to this problem elegantly?

Comment: I don't see offhand how this theorem has anything at all to do with a proof of this fact. There are simple and obvious proofs, right? The sets $\{a\}\times B$ are pair wise disjoint and all of the same size as $B$, and there are as many of them as the size of $A$. Their union exhausts $A\times B$, so $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot|B|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I_n = \{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$. You may define a set $X$ to be finite if there is a bijection from $X$ to some $I_n$. In this sense, you want to prove that
$$
I_m \ \times I_n \sim I_{mn}
$$
where $\sim$ means *has the same cardinality as*. This will prove that $A \times B$ is finite when $A \sim I_m$ and $B \sim I_n$.

This can be done using the Division with Remainder Theorem by sending $$x \in I_{mn} \mapsto (q+1,r+1) \in I_m \ \times I_n$$ where $q,r$ are the quotient and remainder of the division of $x-1$ by $n$.